# Setting clustered index in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, indexing, clustered-index

I'm trying to define a property that is not the id as a clustered index in nhibernate, yet I've found no way of doing this.

Could anyone give me a pointer of how this is done, or it is something not currently available in nhibernate?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<database-object>` to create indexes and other artifacts.

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-database-object